# C: Pointer confusion

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue, post-increment

I understand this is part of the basic stuff, but i am stuck :-(
Can someone please help me?

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
 int a=1,b=2,c;
 c=(a+b)++;
}
```

Why is the output an error? lvalue required?

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char *p1="name";
 char *p2;

 p2=(char*)malloc(20);
 memset(p2,0,20);

 while(*p2++=*p1++);
 printf("%s\n",p2);

}
```

Why is the output, an empty string? And if i reverse the order of increment, that is: `while(++*p2=++*p1);`, why the lvalue error comes?

Comment: "kiss", avoid one liners like while(*p2++=*p1++); It is better to break that line into a more readable multi line with a clear "loop until", "inc" and copy part. Instead of doing it all at once.

Comment: @Johan: If things are made that straight forward, it won't be a part of tricky interview question :-)

Comment: you are right about the question (and to learn something new) but simpler code tend to work better in the long run ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first question,`(a+b)++` means "increment the value of `a+b` by 1".

You cannot increment `a+b`, though, for it's not a variable. What would you expect to happen in the following code?

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
printf("a = %d, b = %d, a+b = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
(a+b)++;
printf("a = %d, b = %d, a+b = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
```

Clearly the first `printf` should print

> a = 1, b = 2, a+b = 3

But what about the second one?

> a = ?, b = ?, a+b = 4

It's not clear what a or b should be if we increment the sum.

As for the second question, remember that you're changing `p2` when you copy over the data, so when you ask to print out what it's pointing at, it's pointing at the end of the string, not the beginning.

An easier way to do the string copy would be to use [`strcpy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy), like so:

```
strcpy(p2, p1);
```

**Note, this is only safe because you know that the size of the string in `p1` isn't greater than the size of `p2`.** If you're not sure about the size of the string (for instance, if you get the string from user input), you'll need to be careful, [as is outlined on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy#Buffer_overflows).

As for why `while(++*p2=++*p1);` doesn't work, while `while(*p2++=*p1++);` does:

Postfix-`++` has higher precedence than `*`. This means, `*p2++` means `*(p2++)`.
So

```
*(p2++) = something;
```

is the same as

```
*p2 = something;
p2 += 1;
```

Meanwhile, `++*p2` means `++(*p2)`, or "whatever `p2` points to, incremented by one".

Again, you get the problem, if you say:

```
 int a = 5, *p2 = &a;
 ++*p2 = 10;
 printf("a = %d\n", a);
```

What would you expect this to print? If anything, it should print 9, because you're telling the compiler that `*p2+1 = 10`.

You can't expect a C-compiler to solve that equation, however, so in order to keep the language simple and efficient, this sort of thing is forbidden.

Comment: very good explanation of the first part. Much more intuitive than simply going on about rvalues and lvalues. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you also help me with the next part of first question? And if i reverse the order of increment, that is: `while(++*p2=++*p1);` why the lvalue required error?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: I've tried to explain it, see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
c=(a+b)++;
```

`a+b` is not a lvalue - how would you want to assign something to the result of an addition (a rvalue) - and the ++/-- operators do assign the new value.

```
while(*p2++=*p1++);
```

---

You p2 points at the `\0` at the end of the string. You need to store the original address p2 points to before your loop:

```
char *p3 = p2;
while(*p2++=*p1++)
    ;
printf("%s\n",p3);
```

Comment: REgarding the first question, then what is the use of post increments? If we do, `a++` this is valid right? Then why not, `(a+b)++`

Answer (score 1):

```
c=(a+b)++;
```

The `++`operator doesn't work with temporary variables. `(a+b)` forms a temporary.

```
while(*p2++=*p1++);
```

You're incrementing `p2` here. After the loop, `p2` no longer points to the beginning of the memory block returned by last `malloc()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the while loop:

while(*p2++ = *p1++);

remember that an expression is "True" in C if it is non-zero, and false if it is zero. Even though the loop has no body, the flow of control is still:

check condition -> execute statement in body --> check condition

and here, "check condition" means "evaluate the statement and see if it is non-zero".

The while loop continues to operate until p1 points to zero, at which point control passes to printf.

e.g.

```
int main() 
{
    int array1[] = {2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 5};
    int array2[20];
    int * p2 = (int *)memset(array2, 0, 20*sizeof(int));
    int * p1 = array1;

    while(*p2++ = *p1++) {
        printf("In while: p1 is %d\n", *p1);
    }
    printf("Out of while: %d\n",*p2);
    return 0;

}
```

yields:

```
In while: p1 is 3
In while: p1 is 1
In while: p1 is 0
Out of while: 0
```